# Python Inferred class hierarchy

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I come from a C# background. While learning any OOP language I usually refer back to an old smalltalk interview question I was once asked.

How do you make a Rock, Paper, Scissors game without any conditional statements?

Here's what I came up with:

game_piece.py

```
"""Game Piece Class represenets the base game piece"""

from __future__ import annotations


class GamePiece:
    """Base class for all game pieces"""
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "<GamePiece>"

    def play(self, game_piece: GamePiece) -> bool:
        """Play method from base class for all game pieces to override.
        This method will call the game piece's specific 'do you beat' method

        :param game_piece: The user's chosen game piece.
        :return: bool
        """
        return \
            game_piece.do_you_beat_paper() | \
            game_piece.do_you_beat_rock() | \
            game_piece.do_you_beat_scissors()

    def do_you_beat_rock(self) -> bool:
        """Every game piece is asked if they can beat a other game pieces.
        Returns a true if it can. Otherwise, returns a false.

        :return: bool
        """
        return False

    def do_you_beat_paper(self) -> bool:
        """Every game piece is asked if they can beat a other game pieces.
        Returns a true if it can. Otherwise, returns a false.

        :return: bool
        """
        return False

    def do_you_beat_scissors(self) -> bool:
        """Every game piece is asked if they can beat a other game pieces.
        Returns a true if it can. Otherwise, returns a false.

        :return: bool
        """
        return False
```

rock.py

```
"""Represents the Rock Game Piece"""

from game_piece import GamePiece


class Rock(GamePiece):
    """This class represents the Rock Game Piece"""

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "<Rock>"

    def play(self, game_piece: GamePiece) -> bool:
        """Call this method to have the game pieces play each other.
        It'll return a true if the game piece is a Paper.
        Otherwise return false.

        :param game_piece: Represents the game piece that it's playing against
        :returns: bool
        """
        return game_piece.do_you_beat_rock()

    def do_you_beat_scissors(self) -> bool:
        """When the opponent game piece is a pair of scissors
        it will call this method on the Rock opponent piece and
        return true to demonstrate that it can beat a pair
        of scissors.

        :return: bool
        """
        return True
```

paper.py

```
"""Represents the Paper Game Piece"""

from game_piece import GamePiece


class Paper(GamePiece):
    """This class represents the Paper Game Piece"""

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "<Paper>"

    def play(self, game_piece: GamePiece) -> bool:
        """Call this method to have the game pieces play each other.
        It'll return a true if the game piece is Scissors.
        Otherwise return false.

        :param game_piece: Represents the game piece that it's playing against
        :returns: bool
        """
        return game_piece.do_you_beat_paper()

    def do_you_beat_rock(self) -> bool:
        """When the opponent game piece is a rock
        it will call this method on the Paper opponent piece and
        return true to demonstrate that it can beat a rock.

        :return: bool
        """
        return True
```

scissors.py

```
"""Represents Scissors Game Piece"""

from game_piece import GamePiece


class Scissors(GamePiece):
    """This class represents the Paper Game Piece"""

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "<Scissors>"

    def play(self, game_piece: GamePiece) -> bool:
        """Call this method to have the game pieces play each other.
        It'll return a true if the game piece is Paper.
        Otherwise return false.

        :param game_piece: Represents the game piece that it's playing against
        :returns: bool
        """
        return game_piece.do_you_beat_scissors()

    def do_you_beat_paper(self) -> bool:
        """When the opponent game piece is a Paper
        it will call this method on the Scissors opponent piece and
        return true to demonstrate that it can beat a Paper.

        :return: bool
        """
        return True
```

main.py

```
"""The main calling program for the game Rock, Paper, Scissors"""

import random
from typing import Any
import click
from game_piece import GamePiece

from paper import Paper
from rock import Rock
from scissors import Scissors


@click.group()
def cli():
    """Required by click"""


@click.command()
@click.option("--selection",
              prompt="Please select: [R]ock, [P]aper or [S]cissors",
              help="The user's selection of either \
                [R]ock, [P]aper or [S]cissors.")
def shoot(selection: str) -> None:
    """The call to 'Shoot' based on the rules
    :param selection: The user's choice
    :return: None
    """
    game_piece_list = {"R": Rock, "P": Paper, "S": Scissors}
    user_selected_game_piece = game_piece_list[selection.upper()]
    mach_selected_game_piece: Any = random.choice(
        list(game_piece_list.items()))
    print(f"You selected {selection} which is {user_selected_game_piece}")
    does_user_win = user_selected_game_piece.play(mach_selected_game_piece)
    print(f"Can {user_selected_game_piece} beat {mach_selected_game_piece}")


cli.add_command(shoot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Rock.play() missing 1 required positional argument: 'game_piece'
```

Since game pieces are chosen at random both by the human & the machine I thought this would work.

Can someone explain how I would infer the type to the base type and accept any child type as a parameter?

Comment: Methods are normally called on *instances* of classes - but you never instantiate any of your classes.  One possible solution would be to decorate your methods with `@staticmethod`, and get rid of the `self` parameter.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - Maybe I might have misunderstood type inference when I was trying to come up with a useful title: Type checking is the process of verifying that the types of operands in a program are compatible with the operator being used. It also ensures that the program is free from type errors before the code is executed. 

Type inference is a generalization of type checking, with many characteristics in common. Type inference is the ability to automatically deduce the type of an expression at compile time. It allows us to omit some or all of the type annotations in our programs.

Comment: Yes, that seems reasonable, but it's not related to the error you got.

Comment: @jasonharper - this was a total rookie mistake. I'm overwhelmed with all the PEP8 & type hinting & making sure I don't annoy other Python Developers in the future with any random code style.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - You're right. I thought maybe OOP in Python was a little different. This was a total rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line

```py
game_piece_list = {"R": Rock, "P": Paper, "S": Scissors}
```

The items in your dict are the classes not instances of these classes. And the `play()` function expects an object of type `GamePiece` (not a class inheriting from `GamePiece`).

So using

```py
game_piece_list = {"R": Rock(), "P": Paper(), "S": Scissors()}
```

should work, as it creates objects of each of the game piece classes.

While this should work, your game logic does not really require instances of the game pieces but only the logic behind them. As proposed by @jasonharper, it would probably make sense to work with static methods here.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm learning the language and it's my own defacto method of trying to understand how OOP works when learning a language. I mentioned smalltalk since OOP is at the forefront of that language. It's not a functional language and you're forced to use objects.